# Can you jinx someone?

Tags: halacha, words, curse

Since I was a child it was common that when two people would say the same thing at the same time one would call out "jinx" (sometimes followed by, "you have to buy me a soda!"). Nothing else seems to actually happen or be implied by *jinxing* someone.

Doing some research on on jinx [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx) tells me it implies some kind of charm or curse. I don't know if that meaning is still in use. I would like to know if any halachic authority discuss the permissibility (or not) of using this term.

Comment: To be clear, you are not asking about (a) whether the children's game may be played (b) whether one may place a jinx on someone, (c) whether belief in being jinxed is permitted, but (d) simply whether the word "jinx" may be used? If the latter, is there some reason to think it ought not be used anymore so than the word "curse" or "hex"?

Comment: My memory from first grade is that the game is that person who gets jinxed is not allowed to talk until somebody says their name